# changing ruby modules without restarting rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails application, i have modules which are required and included in the controllers.
The problem is: i have to restart the application every time i make any changes in these modules.
Any solutions?

---

Example

included module

```
#rails_application/lib/services/test.rb

module Services
  module TestService
    def start
      'Service started successfully'
    end
  end
end
```

controller

```
#rails_application/app/controllers
class TestController < ApplicationController

  require 'services/test.rb'
  include Services::TestService

  def index
   render :text => start
  end

end
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include code that shows how you are including the modules in your controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In development, it should reload every you access.
In production mode, you can turn off cache by modifying

```
config/environments/production.rb
```

Change the following line to false.

```
config.cache_classes = false
```

And restart the application.

It reloads the changes without restarting the server.

---

Update
You might try `load` instead of `require`.

```
load 'services/test.rb'
```

Comment: No, this happens in the development mode